# Redirect mirror url wihout URI to same url with URI

Tags: .htaccess, url, uri, mirror

I'm using **www.rosariodesign.com** as main domain, but also **www.congresoead.com** as a mirror domain. When someone enter using the mirror domain, it must be redirect to mirror domain /congreso (congresoead.com -> congresoead.com/congreso). Only in the mirror domain case.

I'm trying with this code in htaccess, but it's replacing the domain and mantaining the URI:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^congresoead\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.congresoead.com/congreso [L,R=301]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, www was interrupting the code, this was the code that worked:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?congresoead\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.congresoead.com/congreso [L,R=301]
```